# Create foreach for a value that exists twice

Tags: php

I have the following statement which `SELECT`s `ProductName` and `Quantity` from the `orderDetails` table. See below:

```
try {       
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ProductName, Quantity FROM orderDetails WHERE OrderID = :OrderID");
    $stmt->bindParam(':OrderID', $_SESSION['newOrderID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $_POST['ProductName'] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

If `$_POST['ProductName']['ProductName']` exists more than once how can I create a foreach loop based on that?

**What I have tried so far...**

```
foreach($_POST['ProductName']['ProductName']) {

}
```

This did not work...

**What have I done wrong?**

**Complete Code:**

```
try {       
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ProductName, Quantity FROM orderDetails WHERE OrderID = :OrderID");
    $stmt->bindParam(':OrderID', $_SESSION['newOrderID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    array_push($_POST["ProductName"], $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// echo $_POST['ProductName']['ProductName'];
// echo $_POST['ProductName']['Quantity'];

try {       
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT Stock FROM products WHERE ProductName = :ProductName");
    $stmt1->bindParam(':ProductName', $_POST['ProductName']['ProductName']);
    $stmt1->execute();
    $_POST['Stock'] = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

// echo $_POST['Stock']['Stock'];

$_POST['DEDUCT'] = $_POST['Stock']['Stock'] - $_POST['ProductName']['Quantity'];

try {       
    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare("UPDATE products SET Stock = :Stock WHERE ProductName = :ProductName");
    $stmt2->bindParam(':Stock', $_POST['DEDUCT']);
    $stmt2->bindParam(':ProductName', $_POST['ProductName']['ProductName']);
    $stmt2->execute();
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Try using `array_push($_POST["ProductName"], $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` to add it to the array instead of overwriting the value of `$_POST["ProductName"]`

Comment: What is your requirement? You can use mysql distinct function to prevent duplicate values.

Comment: Exists more than one times in the database? In different rows?

Comment: I have added the complete code so you can see what I am trying to achive. I am new to PHP so this may be an awful way of doing things.

Comment: Instead of creating a`foreach` simply update your query with `group by` clause within

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new array called (for example, `$rows`) which contains all of the fetched data using the function `fetchAll()` (`fetch()` only retrieves the next one row).

The most straightforward way to do this is as follows:

```
try {       
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ProductName, Quantity FROM orderDetails WHERE OrderID = :OrderID");
    $stmt->bindParam(':OrderID', $_SESSION['newOrderID'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    //Add all returned values to an array called "$rows"
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then if you want to access that data later you can do:

```
foreach($rows as $row){
    var_dump($row); //Show the data in the row to double-check
}
```

Comment: I would initialize `$rows = array();` inside the `catch` to prevent errors on the `foreach` loop if the query fails.

Comment: I have added the complete process of what I am trying to achive. What I have does work but only if there is ONE product assigned to the Order ID, if I have two it doesn't update correctly.

Comment: @Heru-Luin In all honesty, I'd connect to the database in a `try/catch` and then check if the query goes through using an `if(!$stmt->execute())` function and initiate the array afterwards... but yes that would work!

Comment: @BenPearlKahan I am trying to work with this now. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create array using foreach like this :

```
$newval_arr = array(); 
foreach($_POST['ProductName']['ProductName'] as $key=>$value) {
  if(!in_array($value,$newval_arr) || empty($newval_arr))
  {
     $newval_arr[] = $value;
  }
}
```

Then after you can use $newval_arr in foreach

```
foreach($newval_arr as $key=>$value)
{
  //Your code herer
}
```

Comment: Thank you for assisting me. I take it the first block of code you provided me would go below the first catch and the foreach loop itself would go around the rest of the try and catch?

Comment: Please tick mark this answer if it is useful to you. Thanks